# Get outputs from convolutional autoencoder in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a convolutional autoencoder in TensorFlow. I want to feed this to an LSTM, but I am not sure how to connect the two networks. One way I was thinking of is just saving the output to a file and letting a separate LSTM read them in.

If I have an input x, how do I feed it to the network and get the encoded version back? Similarly, how do I decode it?

Is the encoding something like?:

```
new_batch = sess.run([hidden2], feed_dict={x:x_batch})
```

Is there a better way of doing it, i.e. building an RNN directly on top of the encoder? Can't seem to find any examples/tutorials on this.

```
n_inputs = 12 * 24
n_hidden1 = 150
n_hidden2 = 80
n_hidden3 = n_hidden1
n_outputs = n_inputs
learning_rate = 1e-4

def conv2d(x, w):
return tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, strides = [1, 1, 1, 1], padding = 'SAME')


initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(mode="FAN_AVG", uniform=True)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_inputs], name='input_placeholder') # x: batch_size x n_inputs
batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]
print("x shape:", x.get_shape())

x_image = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 24, 12, 1])
print("x_image shape:", x_image.get_shape())

weight1 = tf.Variable(initializer([3, 3, 1, n_hidden1]))
print("weight1 shape:", weight1.get_shape())
bias1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(n_hidden1))
print("bias1 shape:", bias1.get_shape())
hidden1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, weight1)+bias1)
print("hidden1 shape:", hidden1.get_shape())

weight2 = tf.Variable(initializer([3, 3, n_hidden1, n_hidden2]))
print("weight2 shape:", weight2.get_shape())
bias2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(n_hidden2))
print("bias2 shape:", bias2.get_shape())
hidden2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(hidden1, weight2)+bias2)
print("hidden2 shape:", hidden2.get_shape())

weight3 = tf.Variable(initializer([3, 3, n_hidden2, n_hidden3]))
print("weight3 shape:", weight3.get_shape())
bias3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(n_hidden3))
print("bias3 shape:", bias3.get_shape())
hidden3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(hidden2, weight3)+bias3)
print("hidden3 shape:", hidden3.get_shape())

hidden3_reshaped = tf.reshape(hidden3, shape=[-1, n_outputs * n_hidden3])
print("hidden3 reshaped:", hidden3_reshaped.get_shape())

weight4 = tf.Variable(initializer([n_outputs * n_hidden3, n_outputs]))
print("weight4 shape:", weight4.get_shape())
bias4 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(n_outputs))
print("bias4 shape:", bias4.get_shape())
outputs = tf.matmul(hidden3_reshaped, weight4)+bias4
print("outputs shape:", outputs.get_shape())

mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - x))
loss = mse

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    #init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    #saver = tf.train.Saver()


#def train_network(g, num_epochs):
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    #print(seq_reshaped.eval())
    #print(seq_multiple_reshaped.eval())
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    #training_losses = []

    for idx, batch in enumerate(gen_epochs(3)):
        training_losses = 0
        print("epoch", idx)
        step = 0
        for x_batch in batch:
            step = step + 1
            #print(len(x_batch))
            _, b_loss = sess.run([training_op, loss], feed_dict={x:x_batch})
            print("batch", step, ", batch loss:", b_loss)
            training_losses = training_losses+b_loss
        training_losses = training_losses/step
        print("epoch average loss:", training_losses)

    # saving the session to a file
    saver.save(sess, "saves/autoencoder")
```

Comment: Do you want to connect a "trained" autoencoder to a LSTM or do you want to train the whole thing? From your code, it seems that you wish to connect both before training. Have you looked at the tf.contrib.layers module? It includes easy to use functions that allow you to connect a CNN to a LSTM. Try looking at tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d and tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell

Comment: So instead of tf.nn.conv2d, I should use tf.contrib.layers.conv2d ? Any suggestions on where I could find an example on this? (I'm quite new with TensorFlow)

Comment: As for the decision to train them separately or together as 1 big network, I suppose the latter may be more accurate, but harder to train?

Comment: Exactly. You can try having a look at this page: https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators

Comment: Thanks. To see the outputs of a batch in the autoencoder, are they reachable by this command? new_batch = sess.run([outputs], feed_dict={x:x_batch}). I would like to be able to get the transforned batch ? And likewise, I need to be able to go from Y to X